# OSM2 VectorTiles lat/long to tile

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, sqlite, mbtiles

After a frustrating few days I came to the conclusion that the [Slippy Map Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Lon..2Flat._to_tile_numbers_5) only works for raster tiles, not for [OSM2VectorTiles](http://OSM2VectorTiles.org) data. I can work with the data once I find the correct tile_data BLOB, but actually locating the correct tile via a user lat/long is problematic. The equations given in the wiki above identify raster tiles correctly, but I'm trying to get this working for an offline version of OpenStreetMap rendering/navigation (meaning I can't just use mapbox's JS API to convert it, also I can't find where the conversion happens in the github repo).

Can anyone offer any advice as to how I can convert a lat/long to the correct tile in an OSM2VT SQLite database?

The query, that works for raster tiles, may be of some use:

```
    public void UserQuery()
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter a latitude value: ");
        double userLat = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter a longitude value: ");
        double userLong = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        _merc.TileLat = Math.Floor((1.0 - Math.Log(Math.Tan(DegreesToRadians(userLat)) + 1.0 / Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(userLat))) / Math.PI) * Math.Pow(2, ZoomLevel));
        _merc.TileLong = Math.Floor((userLong + 180.0) / 360.0 * Math.Pow(2, ZoomLevel));
    }
```

Comment: cross-posted: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/50699/osm2-vectortiles-latlong-to-tile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the following code from [tilemaker](http://github.com/systemed/tilemaker) relevant:

https://github.com/systemed/tilemaker/blob/master/src/coordinates.cpp

I don't have any experience with osm2vectortiles because I find Docker and npm about as appealing as sandpapering my eyeballs, but I presume it uses the same tile layout.